# How to extend the PreferenceCategory class

Tags: android, xml

I have extended the PreferenceCategory class. It works except the Android attribute "title" is not being passed through and displaying on the screen. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

**xml\preferences_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="advanced_settings_screen"> 
    <apps.test.CustomPreferenceCategory
        android:key="advanced_general_settings_category"
        android:title="@string/general_category">

        <!-- Other Preferences Here -->

    </apps.test.CustomPreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**CustomPreferenceCategory.java**

```
public class CustomPreferenceCategory extends PreferenceCategory {

    public CustomPreferenceCategory(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Log.v("Constructor 1");
        this.setLayoutResource(R.layout.custom_preference_category);

            String titleAttribute = _attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "title");
            if(titleAttribute.startsWith("@")){
                titleAttribute = _context.getString(Integer.parseInt(titleAttribute.replace("@", "")));
            }

        //What can I do here to populate the custom view with the title? I can't seem to figure this part out.

    }

    public CustomPreferenceCategory(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        Log.v("Constructor 2");
        this.setLayoutResource(R.layout.custom_preference_category);
    }

}
```

**layout\custom_preference_category.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget_frame"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="TEST" />          
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/category_divider"
        android:src="@drawable/preference_divider_normal"
        android:layout_height="2dip"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I just want the attribute "TITLE" to pass through and display on the screen. I am able to get the "title" attirbute, but now I can't seem to figure out how to set the title into the custom View. Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the AttributeSet to get the title:

```
mTitle = attrs.getAttributeValue(androidns, "title");
```

Where androidns is:
 `private static final String androidns = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";`

**edit:** Added information on using the title....

Add your layout to the preference in xml:

```
android:layout="@layout/profile_preference_row"
```

Now you will need to override the onBindView  (sample below from android source)...

```
@Override
protected void onBindView(View v) {
    super.onBindView(v);

 TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title); 
 if (textView != null) {
     textView.setText(getTitle());
  .......removed code.....

 }
```

Comment: Great :) I now have the title. (I updated the question with the new question and new code as well.) How do I set the title into the View now? Can you help me with this?